# How to track files installed from source code?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, compiling

When we install a package with package management, this program is able to track files which belongs to application.

But when we compile and install a application from source code, package management can not see this application.

How can we track all files installed from source code?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to "track" all applications you install from source code.

When you install from source, some scripts copy some files somewhere.

That is the main reason why package management has been implemented.

You can track yourself what you install by e.g. keeping all sources in one place.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `checkinstall`. From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall:

> CheckInstall keeps track of all files installed by a "make install" or
>   equivalent, creates a Slackware, RPM, or Debian package with those
>   files, and adds it to the installed packages database, allowing for
>   easy package removal or distribution.

You can install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

Comment: This is a way how to create a deb package and then use package management. There are many ways to do it.